# iOS - UIView animateWithDuration not working properly

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios10, uiprogressview

I'm trying to do some animation to my UIProgressView when i finished upload a photo to my server. When i set the duration to 5.0 or 10.0 seconds, it it not different and the completition is called immediately.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.progressBar.progress = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"kykny udah");
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"finished");
            Post *post = [mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@""];
            [self.posts insertObject:post atIndex:0];

            NSLog(@"caption: %@ , items: %@",post.caption, post.items);

            CGRect frame = self.progressView.frame;
            frame.size.height = 0;
            self.progressView.frame = frame;

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
```

how come this issue happens ? It is just like a normal sequence code in reality

Comment: Have you tried this same code in iOS 9 or earlier versions ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803464/uiview-animatewithduration-and-uiprogressview-setprogress

Comment: BTW: You should not misuse animations for timers. The _controller code_ should not be done in the completion block. Why should the user wait for an operation which can be done immediately? Why don't you hide the progress view setting it's `hidden` property to `YES`?

Comment: because then i hide my progressView, my tableView won`t go to the top and  it makes the gap with the height of my progressView

Comment: @macmoonshine
i have seen that, and i have check if `finished` parameter as you can see in my code above, and i have try to include the dispatch function, but still, it is weird

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line after updating your frame changes like

```
self.progressBar.progress = 1.0;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

This will make your animation effect for the time you specified in animation duration.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show just the progress for 10sec then

```
// PROGRESS VIEW IS JUST A VIEW WITH SOME BACKGROUND COLOR WITH FRAME CGRectMake(0,0,0,10)
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
self.progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,10); // adjust the frame to get  the linear animation view
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
NSLog(@"kykny udah");
if (finished) {
    .....
    self.progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,0);
    .....
}
}];
```

Comment: The OP wants animate the bar not the frame.

Comment: if its just a bar then get the subviews and then adjust the frame

Comment: then why the user is setting the frame in the completin block

Comment: He sets the height of the frame to zero to hide the progress view.

Comment: yeah, i change the height to hide my progressView because if i change the visibility to hidden, my TableView still in it`s place and it will has a gap with the height of my progressView between the top screen and the cell