# Add completion handler to setProgress UIProgressView function - Swift

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

UIProgressView has a function called `setProgress` that doesn't have a completion handler.

I would like to execute code after the progress has been animated like this:

`self.setProgress(1, animated: true)`

How can I do that using Swift?

EDIT:

In order to animate the progressView, I added this function inside the subclass

```
func makeProgress(with duration: Double) {
        self.progress = 0.0
        progressLevel.completedUnitCount = 0
        isHidden = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: (duration/(units-20)), repeats: true) { (timer) in
            guard self.progressLevel.isFinished == false else {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
            self.progressLevel.completedUnitCount += 1
            self.setProgress(Float(self.progressLevel.fractionCompleted), animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own animation, with completion handler, as described here: [UIView animateWithDuration and UIProgressView setProgress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803464/uiview-animatewithduration-and-uiprogressview-setprogress)

Comment: I have seen that answer, but using UIView.animate doesn't work for me. I am using a different approach that I put in the question edit.

Comment: What is the problem you get with animate ?

Comment: it doesn't animate yet, it jumps right into the final state